# Change ALL icons in sytem tray

Tags: kde, icons, themes, plasma

When I change the icon theme on my Kubuntu 22.04 it only applies to some of the system tray icons:

before (Breeze Icon Theme):
[image: before]

after (Kora Icon Theme):
[image: after]

As you can see it only changes the icons of the running applications (left to right: KeepassXC, Nextcloud, Telegram Desktop) but not of the "system related" icons like battery, sound and wifi.
As I understand the whole thing, these are defined by the plasma-style-theme and the application icons are defined by the icon-theme.

Now the question is if there is an easy way to apply an icon theme to all the icons at once?

I was also wondering if there is an easy way to find the icon paths of the used icons? I already found out that the Kora icons for the system tray are stored in `/home/reneas/.local/share/icons/kora/panel` but it's really annoying to look through the thousands of icons to finde the one I want to modify.